# Java Observable List item get deleted while updated by thread

Tags: java, multithreading, observablelist

I am writing a code where an observable list A is getting updated by a separate thread and when a new item get updated in this list, the listener send the same item to another list (call List B) for further calculation. This list B suppose take 5 items and do calculation and then remove old items and take new items from List A. Presently my code while removing item from List B also removes same item from List A which i don't want and List B still have one previous item. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```html
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Window_Demo1 implements Runnable {

/**
 * @param args
 */

 public static ObservableList<Integer> lstA = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
 public static List<Integer> win = new ArrayList<>();
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Window_Demo1 demo = new Window_Demo1();
     Thread thread = new Thread(demo);
     thread.start();
     addtolstB(lstA,win);

 }
 
 public static void addtolstB(ObservableList<? extends Integer> items, List<Integer> lstB) {
  items.addListener((ListChangeListener<Integer>) c-> {
         while (c.next()) {
             if (c.wasAdded()) {
              lstB.addAll(c.getAddedSubList());
              System.out.println(lstB.toString()+ "Lst B Added: "+ Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
              
              if(lstB.size()==5) {
               items.removeAll(lstB);
              }
             }
             if (c.wasRemoved()) {
              lstB.removeAll(c.getRemoved());
              System.out.println(lstB.toString());
             }
         }
  });

     for (Integer item : items) {
      lstB.add(item);
     }
 }

 /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
  */
 @Override
 public void run() {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

   lstA.add(i);
   System.out.println(lstA.toString()+ "Publisher Added: "+i+" at time: "+Instant.now().getEpochSecond());

   try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }

 
  
 }

}
```

The problem in this code is:
[image]

Comment: You quite clearly remove all items from A that are in B once B has 5 items: `items.removeAll(lstB);` Why?

Comment: Why did you choose `ObservableList`?

Comment: it shud be lstB.clear(). Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko... because it provide an inbuilt listener and any update or removal can easily be handled. Initially the system will have multiple separate threads continuously updating different list at different streaming rate so found Observable list more handy   as compare to using listener from List class.